# Java - How to filter rows in dataframe that have null values for specific columns

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

In Java I have a `df` that looks like this:

| NAME | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name_1 | null | some_value |
| name_2 | some_value | null |
| name_3 | null | null |

I want to filter all rows that have null values for COLUMN_1 and COLUMN_2 so that the new dataset looks like:

| NAME | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name_1 | null | some_value |
| name_2 | some_value | null |

How do I keep the rows that have at least one value in COLUMN_1 and COLUMN_2

I tried the following filters but it seems the `and` statement is sequential and removes all rows from the df:

```
Column filter = col("COLUMN_1").isNotNull().and(col( "COLUMN_2").isNotNull());
df.filter(filter).show();
```

How do I keep the rows that have at least one value in COLUMN_1 and COLUMN_2

Answer (score 2):

With your filter you are requesting that **both** `COLUMN_1` and `COLUMN_2` must be not null in order to be included in the result.

What you really want is that **at least one** of `COLUMN_1` and `COLUMN_2` are not null, which can be achieved with an `or`:

```java
Column filter = col("COLUMN_1").isNotNull().or(col("COLUMN_2").isNotNull());
```